# How to set default value of ProductType attribute in Commercetools platform?

Tags: platform, commercetools

I wanna to set up default value if a `ProductType` attribute is empty or null.

This is the documentation I referred: https://commercetools.github.io/commercetools-jvm-sdk/apidocs/io/sphere/sdk/meta/ProductAttributeDocumentation.html

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no default value that can be defined in product type attributes.

You could create a [custom object](https://docs.commercetools.com/http-api-projects-custom-objects#customobject) for that purpose.

How do you plan to manage your product data?
Will you sync from an external system?

Comment: I plan manage my products through the Merchant Center. So, I wanna see some value in attributes,  after it was added to product type.

Comment: There is no way to define default values on most attribute types. You can define values for enumtype. But still no default value.  see docs  https://docs.commercetools.com/http-api-projects-productTypes#enumtype .  Does that help? Best Regards Brian